# Is it semantically correct to use a <p> inside my <header>

Tags: html

I already have a h1 tag somewhere else in the page, now I've just made a form and I added a header and footer tag to the form to make everything semantically, now I'm wondering if I can put a p inside my header instead of an h1, h2, h3 for example

```html
<form>
  <header>Try it free 7 days then $20/mo. thereafter</header>

  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First name" />
  <input ... />
  <input ... />
  <button type="submit">Claim your free trial</button>

  <footer>
    By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our Terms and Services
  </footer>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: @LeeTaylor there is a lot of html that will look fine even if it is wrong.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann Yes, but it seemed that the OP hadn't even tried it...

Comment: They want a document that is semantically well-formed. There is no immediate sign when a document isn't, because browsers don't make much use of these finer points of structure. But some screenreader may, or a search engine spider, or a future browser version, or some browser plugin... none of which can be observed.

Answer (score 0):

[The MDN page for the `<header>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) states that [*Flow content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) (except for a descendent `<header>` or `<footer>` element) is semantically allowed within the content of `<header>`, which would necessarily *include* the `<p>` element.

This is consistent with the *Content model* spec defined in [the HTML standard for `<header>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element).

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, a `<p>` inside `<header>` is allowed. Semantically, it only makes sense if we are talking about something actually paragraph-shaped, i. e. an introduction.

If it's a short fragment, an actual (sub-)headline, you may want to look into splitting your document into several `<section>`s, each of which can have its own `<h1>`.

Answer (score -1):

actually no , because of CEO
In other words you can use the following convenient elements inside of a header tag in HTML5: a, em, strong, code, cite, span, br, img. See the full list here.
The W3C validator will give you the following error if you will try to validate this markup.

Comment: "*actually no , because of CEO*" Chief Operating Officer? What does that have to do with this question? "*See the full list here.*" Where, exactly? You haven't included a link to the source upon which you're basing your claim. "*The W3C validator will give you the following error if you will try to validate this markup.*" What error?